# Correct use of sphinx tabularcolumns directive

Tags: python, html, python-sphinx, docutils

I'm trying to center a single table column using the `tabularcolumns` directive as documented http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/misc.html?highlight=tabularcolumns#tables

Simple example:

```
.. tabularcolumns:: |C|l|

+----------+------+
| Num      | Name |
+==========+======+
| 1        | One  |
+----------+------+
| 2        | Two  |
+----------+------+
```

According to my reading, this should center the first column, but the HTML output of column one is always left aligned.  Am I misreading or misunderstanding something?

Using sphinx-build version 1.3.1

Comment: The `tabularcolumns` directive only applies to LaTeX output.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Thanks for your help.